# Would a simple experiment show that pressure transmits through water at the speed of sound?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, speed

Let say we have a 100 m long metal pipe with its two ends equally positioned at 1 m above the rest of the pipe. The ideal case would be a U-shaped pipe... The pipe is whole filled with water. Now, if we press the water at one end of the pipe should we see a time delay before the water spills out from the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there should be a time delay that could be measured experimentally.

A good way would be to use a long U shaped tube and measure the length as accurately as possible.  Film the experiment with high speed film that does a certain number of frames per second.  Drop a weight onto the liquid, that covers most of the area at one end of the tube and by seeing how many frames pass from the moment the weight hits, until the disturbance is visible at the other end - you would find the time.

Then from the length and the time the velocity of the pressure transmission could be calculated.

Comment: In principle this might work, since the speed of sound in water is about 1480 m/s so the propagation delay in a 100m pipe would be about 67 ms. However you might actually be measuring the speed of sound in the *pipe,* not the water. In a steel pipe for example, the speeds of shear waves and compression waves are about 3200 and 6000 m/s. If you used a relatively flexible plastic pipe, the deformation of the pipe would affect the result and damp out the traveling wave.